# Exec("adduser myownuser") not working on CentOS server

Tags: php, linux, nginx, centos

I have CentOS 7 with `PHPFPM` and `Nginx` (both installed from source, not yum). `Nginx` and `PHP` running on `www-data` user and group. Now I create a `PHP` file with this content:

```
exec("adduser myownuser");
```

This `PHP` file work successfully if I run it in the CentOS console as root. But when I want to run it in my webserver root, nothing happens and the script run as `www-data`..

What is the problem ?

Comment: use exec("sudo adduser myownuser");

Comment: not working with your suggestion. it seams the problem is for permissions not command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add apache to sudoers, without password required.
also you need to execute the adduser via a one line script, you can't set it's password otherwise.

Here's my implementation

```
$ccmd = "nohup sudo useradd -d /home/user -p $(openssl passwd -1 " . $thepassword . ") username &";
exec($ccmd);
```

I added this to my sudoers file

apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

depending on your distro, your apache user may differ. To find out what apache's username is, you can echo exec("whoami");

Before people start yelling at me, it's best to only allow apache sudo access to the one command you need. Either that or add apache to a group and assign that group to that command. I won't explain how to do that here, you can search because there are threads about this everywhere

Comment: then execute whoami and see what the username is, and add that to sudoers. Also remember to edit sudoers with vi and not nano or any other text editor. And if you have SELinux on, you'll have to stop it